# Save Plugin Options as Array

Tags: options, plugin-options

I am trying to create a simple option page. The options consist of a text field per user role. But I don't want to edit the code every time I add a new user role.

So I am trying to "for each"- user roles and build text fields from it. But the value does not get saved in the options. I think I need to save the values in an array before save.

Like this:

```
add_settings_field( 
'weborder_leveranstext',
__( 'Header', 'weborder' ), 
'weborder_leveranstext_render', 
'pluginPage', 
'weborder_pluginPage_leveransalternativ'
```

);

```
function weborder_leveranstext_render(  ) {

   $options = get_option( 'weborder_settings' );
    
   global $wp_roles;
   $all_roles = $wp_roles->get_names();

   foreach ($all_roles as $role => $value) {
      echo '<input type="text" name="??" value="' . $options['weborder_leveranstext'] . '">';
   }
}
```

I have tried a lot of thing but I think that this must be saved in array.
I have tried similar thing to this without success:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="weborder_leveranstext_'.$role.'" value="' . $options['weborder_leveranstext_'.$role.''] . '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey I got it. I was close the whole time :)

```
function weborder_leveranstext_render(  ) {

$options = get_option( 'weborder_settings' );
    
global $wp_roles;
$all_roles = $wp_roles->get_names();

foreach ($all_roles as $role => $value) {
    echo '<br><span style="width: 180px; display: inline-block;">' . $value . '</span>';
    echo '<input type="text" style="width: 300px;" name="weborder_settings[weborder_leveranstext]['.$role.']" value="'.$options['weborder_leveranstext'][$role].'">';
}
```

}